# querySelectorAll return an empty object

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, google-chrome-headless

I'm using Chromy framework to scrap a page, so, this is the html:

```
<ul class="a">
<li class="b"></li>
<li class="b"></li>
<li class="b"></li>
<li class="b"></li>
</ul>
```

So, if I do on chrome console the selection like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.b')
```

It will return me a nodeList with 4 objects inside and that's right, but if I do the same selection inside chromy script it return an empty object with 4 empty objects `{ '0': {},'1': {},'2': {},'3': {}}`.

Can you please help me to figure out why this is happening?

That's my Chromy script

```
chromy.chain()
  .goto('https://localhost:8080/')
  .evaluate(() => {
    return document.querySelectorAll('.b');
  })
  .result((r) => console.log(r))
  .end()
  .then(() => chromy.close());
```

Comment: typo? it's correct because you are querying `.a` not `.b`

Comment: Yes... was fixed